# Toolbar in Part Descriptor in eclipse 4

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am new to Eclipse E4. I have a model fragment in which I have added a part descriptor. Now the par is displaying without any issues.

Now I want to add some action items to the part descriptor.

How to do it in a Pure E4 way. Please help.

Thanks & Regards,
Chinniah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Toolbar you check the 'ToolBar' check box on the Part Descriptor.

A 'Toolbar' child will appear in the Part Descriptor. You can add direct or handled  toolitems to the toolbar.

If you add 'handled' toolitems you will also need to define a command and handler.

Handlers can be defined in the Part Descriptor or globally.

Commands are defined globally. You do this in a fragment by adding a fragment that add to the 'commands' feature name of the main application element.